# How to calculate coordinates of a node based on the distances to other nodes and the coordinates of those nodes.

Tags: graph-theory

I am a computer science person, but computer people need math sometimes to solve annoying problems. My problem is related to routing. I have a network of computers that all have coordinates relating to their real-world latency between them. However, I need some way to calculate the coordinates of new nodes joining the network.

When a new node joins the network, it finds the closest nodes (by latency) to it and filters them by which ones have the most consistent latency. It then queries these nodes to figure out their coordinates. Once it has the distances and coordinates, it is supposed to try to find its own coordinates relative to its peers. The coordinates can be either be 2 or 3-dimensional.

This is the part I am having trouble with. I've done some research and tried to implement a [Multidimensional Scaling](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.495.4629&rep=rep1&type=pdf) algorithm to transform pure distances into relational points, but I didn't know how to adjust these relative points to the real coordinates that are queried (and then calculate the individual node's coordinate).

I'm not exactly sure if there is an efficient algorithm to do exactly what I want, but if there is any help would be greatly appreciated : )

Edit: An Example: Lets say there are 3 computers with 3 coordinates each representing their virtual distance from each other (i.e. latency). Another computer bootstraps onto the network and discovers these existing computers and pings the computers to test the distance to each one. Then using the distances and coordinates of these 3 computers, somehow deduces its own coordinates satisfying the the constraints of the measured latencies to all 3 other computers.

Comment: First off, the [tag:dimension-theory-analysis] is intended to deal with various notions of dimension as relates to metric spaces which carry measures (such that Hausdorff dimension of a metric space).  These notions generally connected to the study of fractals.  It doesn't seem relevant here, so I removed it.

Comment: Second, I am not sure that I understand what you are trying to do.  Perhaps you could give us a toy example?  (say, a network with three machines, to which you add one more?)

Comment: Finally, I wonder if you might have more luck asking this question elsewhere on the SE network.  [networkengineering.se] might be appropriate.

Comment: Can we say that the model of your network is a 2D or 3D **complete graph** (in the sense of graph theory ; all **nodes/vertices**  potentialy connected with **links/edges** to any other node) . Moreover, this graph should be **weighted** (all its edges have a number meaning the latency between its two endpoints). Do I interpret the word "latency" in "real-world latency between them" in a correct way ?

Comment: @XanderHenderson thanks for the feedback, I added an example.

Comment: @JeanMarie its not a complete graph once the network gets big enough, each node only measures the real-world latency to the closest nodes to itself to get a more accurate coordinate for itself in the network. (however, if the network is small it is potentially a complete graph). The network can be thought of as a weighted graph as a whole, but each node only has a view of its connected nodes.

Comment: All right. 1) You should use the graph terminology in your question 2) Knowing the "latencies" $L_1,L_2,L_3$ to the three "vertices" that have the 3 smallest latencies is as looking for the intersection of 3 circles. Do you agree ? In fact they will not intersect in a single point : you will have to find an approximate intersection (in the sense of mean squares). Is it what you want ?

Comment: I think so? I'm not sure how that algorithm would scale. Circles would only work for 2 dimensions, so it would have to be spheres for 3 dimensions. And how would I find an approximate intersection? In practice, this wouldn't be only 3 nodes, it could be upwards of 20 to 100 nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a conversation with someone on discord about intersections of 2 & 3 circles and I came up with a kinda inefficient algorithm that does what I'm looking for.

The main issue I'm facing with this problem (which I failed to make clear in the post, sorry!) is how to deal with inaccuracies in the ping measurements.

The algorithm I came up with is to sample every possible combination of 3 nodes and use the intersection of 3 circles to get a bunch of potential locations. Then filter out any outliers and calculate the average coordinate of the sample.

It's kinda unfortunate that this is a pretty inefficient algorithm O(n^3), but I don't know how to go about improving it.